# Binding onChange on ajax return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

I am replacing my select on ajax callback. In the drop down I see the returned list, but when i try to bind change event, it gives me incorrect value. The alert shows me "value is undefined", how do I see the correct value when i change the selected option in my drop down list?

If my dropdown has values ("value1","value2","value3") and if i select "value1", the alert should show me "value is value1".

```
if (status == "success") {

    var mysel = $('#Namelist').empty();


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        mysel.append('<option value="' +
            data[i] + '">' +
            data[i] + '</option>');
    }

    $("#Namelist").replaceWith(mysel);
    $('#Namelist').bind('change', function () {
        alert('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you really need the `$("#Namelist").replaceWith(mysel)`. Also, you should bind the change handler earlier instead of within each AJAX callback.

Answer (score 2):

You should try getting `val()` instead of `attr('value')`:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Ld95ymuL/1/)**

```
$('#Namelist').bind('change', function () {
        alert('Value change to ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: And better use `this.value`

Comment: @A.Wolff `$(this).val()` also deals with multiple selections, whereas `this.value` doesn't, so there's still some advantage as a one-size-fits-all call.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Seems not relevant here but indeed that's a good point, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$("#Namelist").replaceWith(mysel);
```

with

```
$("#Namelist").append(mysel);
```

Then you don't have to bind `event` on `#Namelist` again after `ajax`.

**Complete Code**

```
if (status == "success") {
    var options = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
    }

    $("#Namelist").html(options);
}

// Outside of ajax function
$('#Namelist').on('change', function () {
    alert('Value change to ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) element doesn't typically have an attribute called `value`. To obtain the selected value of such an element you need to query its `.value` property.

jQuery has a handy wrapper for that called [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
$('#Namelist').bind('change', function () {
    alert('Value change to ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Namelist" />
```

I would recommend only binding that change handler once in your page, e.g. when the DOM is ready:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // attach change handler here
});
```

Registering the same event handler more than once is almost always not what you want.

Also, you don't need this call:

```
$("#Namelist").replaceWith(mysel);
```

By that time the select element has already been populated with all the options from your AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

Tip to remove the onChange event from ajax callback was good.

```
Moved the $('#Namelist').on('change',function () {} from ajax callback 

to jQuery(function($) {}); 



 $('#NameList').on('change', function () {
                alert('Value changed to ' + $(this).val());
  });
```